# How to make multiple requests to a JSON/rest API changing a date parameter and save it to a dataframe

Tags: python, rest, api, date, dataframe

I need to query a JSON/rest API for a range of dates. The API contains a date parameter with format ddmmyyyy.
Therefore, I can only query one date. I should be able to loop to query the range of dates.
The objective is to save all the data of the range of dates consulted in a dataframe, to export it to CSV.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
date = '04022018'

res = requests.get("https://api.desarrolladores.datos.gob.cl/mercado-publico/v1/ordenesdecompra/fecha.json/?auth_key=120ee16a05eac5ac399ebee7badf0af264bf5bb9&fecha={}&estado=todos".format(date))

j = res.json()

# print(j)
filename ="temp.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame(j['ordenesDeCompra'])

print(df.head())
df.to_csv(filename)
```

With that code I can save the result in a dataframe and in a CSV, but I do not know how to go through a range of dates. I assume that with "for x in range" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL_FORMAT_STRING = "https://api.desarrolladores.datos.gob.cl/mercado-publico/v1/ordenesdecompra/fecha.json/?auth_key=120ee16a05eac5ac399ebee7badf0af264bf5bb9&fecha={}&estado=todos"

import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2018, 2, 4)
for i in range(<as many days as you want to iterate over>):
    date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    result_for_date = requests.get(URL_FORMAT_STRING.format(date.strftime(%Y%m%d)))
```